# 'StringLinkedList' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, c++11, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am getting this error

'StringLinkedList' was not declared in this scope

here is my code

i cannot figure out why this error occurs

StringNode.h [Header File]

```
#ifndef StringNode_H
#define StringNode_H
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
class StringNode{
private:
    string elem;
    StringNode* next;

friend class StringLinkedList;  
};

#endif
```

StringLinkedList.h [Header File]

```
#include "StringNode.h"
#ifndef StringLinkedList_H
#define StringLinkedList_H

class StringLinkedList{
private:
    StringNode* head;
public:

StringLinkedList();
~StringLinkedList();
bool empty() const;
const string& front() const;
void addFront(const string& e);
void removeFront();
void displaylist();
};

#endif
```

StringLinkedList.cpp

```
#include "StringLinkedList.H"
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

StringLinkedList::StringLinkedList(){
this->head = NULL;
}
```

mainclass.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
StringLinkedList a;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to `#include "StringLinkedList.H"` in `mainclass.cpp`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to include the header in the module `mainclass.cpp`

Comment: Oh my god !! thanks !! i didn't see